# Insert of bit flag values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the user can input a name for an `instructor` and/or `faculty` person. Based on the fields submitted I want to store values into the `person` table. If both an instructor and faculty values are submitted I would like to create a different row for each and be able to identify their role `instructor` or `faculty`. I in the table I have bit flags to help determine the `role`. But how can I store the bit value in the table to identify if it’s either `instructor` or `faculty?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $bitmask = 1|2;

    $db_con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
    $db_insert  = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO person (`person_name`,`instructor_role`) 
        VALUES (?,?)"); 
    $db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['instructor_name'], $bitmask);
        $db_insert->execute();
}    ?>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">

Instructor Name:<input type="text" name="instructor_name">
Faculty Name:<input type="text" name="contact_name">


<input value="SAVE" name="submit" type="submit">

</form>
```

*Table*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `contact_role` bit(8) NOT NULL,
  `instructor_role` bit(8) NOT NULL,
  `person_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`person_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what you want:

```
$bit =1;
$bit2 = 2;
$bit3= 4;
$bit4= 8;
//1+2+8=11
$result = $bit | $bit2 |$bit4;
//this is still 11
$result = $result | $bit;
```

if you need the SQL part please tell, will update

depends how you define instructor value and faculty

i will assume instructor is 1 and faculty is 2

not sure if bit is i or something else so please check it

```
$db_insert  = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO person (`person_name`,`instructor_role`) 
            VALUES (?,?)"); 
            $db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['instructor_name'] || $_POST['faculty_name']);
    $db_insert->bind_param('i',1|2);

$db_insert->execute();
```

Comment: I am getting an error `$db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['instructor_name'] || $_POST['faculty_name']);` [LINK_SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/test/test2.php)

Comment: if you want to store both names you either have to store it in two rows, or use foreign keys to bind those values

the error happens because you cant do both:
$db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['instructor_name'] || $_POST['faculty_name']);
you can either:
$db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['faculty_name']);
$db_insert->bind_param('s', $_POST['instructor_name']);

Comment: Ok then what is `$db_insert->bind_param('i',1|2);` for?

Comment: to specify types,
let's say you have the names stored somewhere in a class as a static field
each field is stored as 2^x
(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,...)
where 1 is Mary,
2 is Bob,
4 is Peter,
8 is Jane,
and so on
if the same person has 2 names (Mary Jane) you put 1|8 which will return 9 which saves space
but those types are used for values that are repeated and are atleast 1 or more of those in the list

Comment: Alright, made the changes but this `$db_insert->bind_param('i',1|2);` is is saying `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

Comment: that means that you need to specify a variable before and pass it there:
$bitmask = 1|2;
$db_insert->bind_param('i',bitmask);

Comment: Alright check my question, I made the changes but nothing is being submitted to the table

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41301/discussion-between-goran-stuc-and-code-ed-student)